# change webpage instantaneously on action off another person

Tags: html, instant

I was wondering if it is (easily) possible to update a webpage when there is an action on another webpage.

Example: I check a checkbox and on another webpage, which is already open, there need to be a change. This must be done instantaneously and the time must be as small as possible.

I do not have any code written yet, so i can't show anything.

My first thought would be to put the result of the checkmark in a database with javascript and check the database with ajax every 10 ms on the other webpage.
But i know this will be too slow for me.

Is there a better way to do this (relatively easy)?

Comment: You're probably looking for web sockets. If you're on .NET, then take a look at SignalR.

Comment: He's not on .Net. He's on HTML/Javascript, obviously

Comment: HTML and JavaScript typically don't exist without a web server. And no server side technology was mentioned. I'm sure whatever server side tech stack is in use has a web sockets implementation.

Comment: He said "checking with Ajax ever 10ms will be too slow"; now show me a webserver/client interaction with single-way latency <5ms.

Comment: Sorry for being not completely clear about server i'm using.
I'm using a Linux/CentOS server with Apache.

I indeed use HTML, PHP, Javascipt and MySQL.

Comment: By the way, "need to check every 10ms" sounds a bit over-the-top. Considering you get the impression of fluid movement at roughly twenty frames per second (==50ms/frame), I doubt there's real reason the browser needs to check something that often.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is usually not possible without both websites coming from the same domain, and that domain establishing communication between the two Javascript sandboxes run in these two windows.

The point here is that what you describe would be called a cross-site-scripting attack (short XSS attack) and is the security nightmare of every browser developer and website admin.

Comment: It sounds more like web sockets than XSS to me.

Comment: web sockets would need to connect to something. I don't know websockets well enough to say whether sandbox-to-sandbox communication on the same host is possible, but it seems unlikely, given the fact that it's hard to make sure that Page A really connects to Page B and not to some eavesdropping Page C, unless you put up *at least* the same restriction you do to direct script access.

Comment: Then i'm lucky i want to do this on the same domain. :)

How would i be able to do this in the same domain?

Comment: Not at all. You will have to communicate over your server, but your <10ms latency requirement won't be fulfilled.

Comment: Could you give me an estimanation on the time it would take for the communication?

Comment: An estimation: Do a ping on your server; multiply max time by two. Add a few milliseconds for handling on the server.